# What data in an mp4 file does ffprobe need to recover duration?

Tags: mpeg-4, ffprobe

In order to minimize read/write traffic in an application, we worked out a strategy that recovers the `ftyp`, `uuid`, and `moov` boxes of mp4s stored in AWS S3, writes them to a local file, then `ffprobe`s that data to recover the movie duration.

This has been working without problems for a long time, but since June 1, 2016, I've been noticing more files hitting ffprobe errors during this process. At first I thought it was because of the `ftyp` these files provided. While they were indeed not any of the ftyps we are spec'd to accept, I nevertheless found that ffprobe *did* work on the original (unabridged) mp4 file.

The errors are similar to this one:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x228c020] stream 0, offset 0x6b8: partial file
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x228c020] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), 1504x1504, 678 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
tmp_9NdLYBkm8sNw5TBNGAz24g_0.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I read several questions mentioning the `analyzeduration` and `probesize` options, and I tried with extremely values, but this **did not** affect the outcome.

I've also triple checked that the `ftyp`, `moov` and `uuid` boxes that were recovered were in fact the same dimensions as those in the original file, so I don't believe them to be at fault for being incomplete.

So, I'm led to believe that we are not recovering everything we need from the mp4. Really, we're hoping not to have to recover the entire `mdat` box. Is there any reason to expect that would be indispensable in some cases?